# View Model value did not set to @Html.HiddenFor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

Hi I have the following Action method in my Controller class:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult MyAction(string foo, Guid? bar)
{
    if(!bar.hasValue)
        bar = Guid.NewGuid();
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel { Foo = foo, Bar = bar };
    return ViewComponent("MyDialog", new {model = viewModel});
}
```

And my view component is:

```
@model MyViewModel
<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Bar)
    <span>@Model.Bar</span>
</div>
```

This was fine when `bar` has value during calling `MyAction()`, if `bar` is `null` then the value of the hidden tag generated does not set to `Guid.NewGuid()`. However the `<span>` tag can always display the correct value from the ViewModel passed.

Why?

Comment: Because the values have been added to `ModelState` in the POST method. You can use `ModelState.Clear()` before updating the property (or change the name of the parameters so they do not match the model properties)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you! May you post it as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Marked it as a dupe instead :)